# How do I properly configure DNS between a Modem and a Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, modem

I have internet provided by Time Warner. As part of our service, they provide us with a wifi-equipped modem. Due to the age and size of our house, we needed an external router instead of using the built-in one.

Which device should have the DHCP Server? We feed the router through one of the Ethernet jacks on the modem. In each device's admin panel, the DHCP server is selected "on". If it matters, roughly 10 devices are connected to the router's network, and we don't use the ones on the modem.

This has only recently become a problem, as the router has begun to assign bogus DNS addresses to devices. They resemble IPv6 addresses but are not. The gateway (192.168.1.1) is also assigned as a DNS. There is very little to no connectivity on those devices, but any PC hardwired to the modem experiences no issues. When connected to the modem's own wi-fi, the DNS assignments are valid.

What do I need to do to fix the errors so that devices are assigned a workable DNS pair? Should I completely disable the DHCP server on the router, or will that render it useless?

ALSO - on the Apple devices, there are two active IPv6 addresses (and sometimes up to 4) on each device, one being a clone of the router.

TIA

Comment: implement the DHCP service on the device that is most centrally accessible to all the hosts. so put it on the ISPs modem, as it will be able to serve IPs to wired, the modem's wifi, and routers wifi all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Only one DHCP server should be active in your local network. If several DHCP servers are active, funny things can happen.

Look at the configuration of your router (you didn't say which one you have) and make it as "dumb" as possible: Basically all it should is to offer a WLAN (or LAN) access point, and forward everything to the modem. Many routers also can be configured to work with the same SSID of the WLAN AP of the modem, so they act as a "backboned" wifi repeater. Details of the configuration depend on your brand of router.